# How to disable --skip-grant-tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to initialize the database for my OpenGTS installation. However, when I run the shell script that accomplishes this, I get the following error:

```
Version: 2.4.5
Database created: gts
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:843] ==> SQLException: DB grant error [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/]
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:843] Message:   The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:843] SQLState:  HY000
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:843] ErrorCode: 1290
[DBAdmin.execCommands:843] java.sql.SQLException: The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
java.sql.SQLException: The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2642)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1647)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1566)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection._executeUpdate(DBConnection.java:961)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.executeUpdate(DBConnection.java:908)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.executeUpdate(DBConnection.java:889)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBProvider.grantDBUser(DBProvider.java:2132)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBAdmin.execCommands(DBAdmin.java:841)
        at org.opengts.db.DBConfig._main(DBConfig.java:1246)
        at org.opengts.db.DBConfig.main(DBConfig.java:1361)
```

I think it's pretty clear that I need to disable --skip-grant-tables, but I am new to MySQL and SQL in general. Recently, I followed a tutorial to reset the MySQL root password and I believe I enabled --skip-grant-tables through that. I've tried looking for solutions to disable this, but haven't come across anything.

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 3):

Just type: `mysqladmin shutdown` and then start MySQL service by running command: `service mysql start`.

:-)

Answer (score 2):

Check your my.cnf file, you probably added that option in there.

Comment: I checked, but no I didn't add that option there. I followed this tutorial before: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/442

Comment: Did you restart Mysql after you followed the tutorial.  If not, you need to... When you restart you should be good to go.

Comment: Solved the issue. I thought I restarted my server, but I didn't because I used `mysql stop`, and got an error: `Stop: Unknown Instance:`, so it didn't really shutdown. I used `mysqladmin shutdown` and it worked.

Comment: Jade's comment did the magic for me. Server had not really stopped.

Comment: Yes, that's what happened to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS=""
```

*(It worked for me.)*

Answer (score 1):

you must have stopped the server and run this

`mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`   due to root pwd chg

so stop the server and start it normal with a start